# How to Save the Excel Active Work Sheet before reading using Apache poi? Is there anything like WorkSheet.save(); or WorkSheet.comit()?

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi, excel-2013

`Workbook workbook = this.getWorkBook(file, path);`
  `Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("WorkArea");`
  `//sheet.save();`
  `// sheet.comit();`

I want to do something like this before reading.So that unsaved data should get saved.

Answer (score 1):

from the following: https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html

You can use a fileoutput stream and write the workbook to it to save to an xls file.

```
Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(); //declare a workbook.

//operations on wb.... create sheets, modify cells.

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("my_workbook.xls"); //create the output stream to write to. (this is the name of the file you are going to be writing to.
wb.write(fos); //Write the workbook to the output stream.
fos.close(); //IMPORTANT, close the output stream.
```

I would read a lot of the article I linked, as it contains a lot of references to Apache POI and is a good read.

I would declare a method for saving, pass in a Workbook and a filename or something like that, such as follows:

```
public void saveWorkbook( Workbook workbook, String saveFileName ) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    //Try with resources, if using Java 7+, otherwise you have to close fileOut manually.
    try( FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream( saveFileName ) )
    {
        workbook.write( fileOut );
    }
}
```

This would be a good way to make sure you are closing your streams everytime, and just good practice.

Comment: Actually my requirement is to read the live Streaming Sheet , and i haven't found any reference for that, please share the knowledge if you have any.

Comment: @KsrimuralikrishnaKsrimuralikr could you save the sheet and then read from the saved xls document or is that not how you want to do it?

Comment: Consider that to be a live Streaming sheet Then how to Save such file programmatic way?